# How to make a hover line above my text that MATCHES the length of my text?

Tags: html, css

I am wanting to make a hover line that appears above my text when I hover my mouse towards the text. However, I want the hover line to be exactly the same length as each of my texts. In case you're wondering, I am wanting to put this effect on my navigation part of HTML.

My HTML (in case you need it)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Satisfy|Tajawal&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="myscripts.js">
    </script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="script/script.js">
    </script>
    <title>Felicity Hayes Official Website</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Felicity Hayes</h1>

<!--- Navigation -->
    <div class="navigation">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Art of Gifting</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Fashion</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Fragrances</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Bridal</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">The House</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="column">
        <img src="img/bag3.jpg">
        <img src="img/bag2.jpg">
        <img src="img/bag1.jpg">
        <img src="img/bag4.jpg">
        <img src="img/bag5.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="textbox-1">
      <p> CAROLINA HERRERA NEW YORK <br> RESORT 2020 </br> </p>
      <button> Discover Now </button>
    </div>

    <div class="textbox-2">
      <p> CAROLINA HERRERA NEW YORK <br> BAD BOY </br> </p>
      <button> Discover Now </button>
    </div>

    <div class="textbox-3">
      <p> CH CAROLINA HERRERA <br> RESORT </br> </p>
      <button> Discover More </button>
    </div>

    <div class= "white-border">
      <p> 212 CAROLINA HERRERA <br> 212 VIP </br> </p>
      <button> Discover More </button>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="column">
        <img src="img/girl1.jpg">
        <img src="img/perfume1.jpg">
        <img src="img/perfume2.jpg">

    <div class="navButton" id="previous">&#10094;</div>
    <div class="navButton" id="next">&#10095;</div>

  </body>

  <footer>
    <button> Sign up to get updates </button>
    <a class="facebook" href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
    <a class="instagram" href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
    <a class="pinterest" href="#"><i class="fab fa-pinterest"></i></a>
    <a class="twitter" href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
    <a class="youtube" href="#"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a>

  </footer>
</html>
```

My CSS:

```
h1 {
  font-family: 'Satisfy', cursive;
  font-size: 70px;
  text-align: center;

}

.navigation ul{
  font-family: 'Tajawal', sans-serif;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

.navigation li{
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  padding: 40px 50px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 70px;
  padding-top: 25px;

}

.navigation a {
  color: #444;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;

}

.navigation a:hover{
  color: pink;
}

.navigation a::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: pink;

  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  width: 0%;
  transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
}

.navigation a:hover::before{
  width: 5%;
}
```

Comment: If you put a fiddle together I'll provide a working example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
      .navigation a:hover:before{
          content:''; /* This Is Required */
          top:0%;
          left:0%;
          background: #fff; /* Change As Your Needs */
          width: 5%;
          height:5px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try update your CSS with below Code

```
.navigation a {
    position: relative;  /* Newly added */
    color: #444;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.navigation a::before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: pink;
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;        /* Newly added */
    width: 0%;
    transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
}

navigation a:hover::before {
    width: 100%;      /* Newly added */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove after from your css .navigation a and try do in hover:

```
.navigation a:hover{
  color: pink;
  padding-top: 15px;
  border-top: 5px solid pink;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution,

I just set `position:relative` to anchor tag

```
.navigation a{
   position:relative;
}
```

and

```
.navigation a::before{
  top: -15px;
}
.navigation a:hover::before{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```css
h1 {
  font-family: 'Satisfy', cursive;
  font-size: 70px;
  text-align: center;

}

.navigation ul{
  font-family: 'Tajawal', sans-serif;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

.navigation li{
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  padding: 40px 50px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 70px;
  padding-top: 25px;

}

.navigation a {
  color: #444;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
      position: relative;

}

.navigation a:hover{
  color: pink;
}

.navigation a::before {
  content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: pink;
    position: absolute;
    top: -15px;
    width: 0%;
    transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
}

.navigation a:hover::before{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Satisfy|Tajawal&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="myscripts.js">
    </script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="script/script.js">
    </script>
    <title>Felicity Hayes Official Website</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Felicity Hayes</h1>

<!--- Navigation -->
    <div class="navigation">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Art of Gifting</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Fashion</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Fragrances</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Bridal</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">The House</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="column">
        <img src="img/bag3.jpg">
        <img src="img/bag2.jpg">
        <img src="img/bag1.jpg">
        <img src="img/bag4.jpg">
        <img src="img/bag5.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="textbox-1">
      <p> CAROLINA HERRERA NEW YORK <br> RESORT 2020 </br> </p>
      <button> Discover Now </button>
    </div>

    <div class="textbox-2">
      <p> CAROLINA HERRERA NEW YORK <br> BAD BOY </br> </p>
      <button> Discover Now </button>
    </div>

    <div class="textbox-3">
      <p> CH CAROLINA HERRERA <br> RESORT </br> </p>
      <button> Discover More </button>
    </div>

    <div class= "white-border">
      <p> 212 CAROLINA HERRERA <br> 212 VIP </br> </p>
      <button> Discover More </button>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="column">
        <img src="img/girl1.jpg">
        <img src="img/perfume1.jpg">
        <img src="img/perfume2.jpg">

    <div class="navButton" id="previous">&#10094;</div>
    <div class="navButton" id="next">&#10095;</div>

  </body>

  <footer>
    <button> Sign up to get updates </button>
    <a class="facebook" href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
    <a class="instagram" href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
    <a class="pinterest" href="#"><i class="fab fa-pinterest"></i></a>
    <a class="twitter" href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
    <a class="youtube" href="#"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a>

  </footer>
</html>
```